# Dplyr indirection / pipe doesn't work inside a closure

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a code which uses dplyr indirection:

```r
library(dplyr)

createGenerator <- function(data, column) 
{
    values <- data %>% pull({{column}})
    function(n)
    {
        values %>% sample(n)
    }
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

df %>% createGenerator(x)(1)
```

It gives me an error

```r
 Error in pull(., { : object 'x' not found
```

However if I don't create a closure it works, like in code below

```r
createGenerator <- function(data, column, n) 
{
    values <- data %>% pull({{column}}) %>% sample(n)
}
```

But I need a possibility to create a closure. What am I missing in closure creation code?

Comment: I've added the pipe to the title - is this what you meant with "indirection"?

Comment: @tjebo I am not sure whether it is about piping, because initial issue was regarding usage of {{}} templating inside custom dplyr function.But if you think it is also related to piping, I am happy with your improvements.

Comment: yeah the issue arises from the use of a pipe - I wasn't so sure what you meant with "indirection" - thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the pipes, specifically the pipe within the enclosed function. I guess there might be a scoping problem, as you are dealing with different environments and also promises rather than existing objects.

No pipe (which I personally prefer, but I guess that's taste)

```r
library(dplyr)

createGenerator <- function(data, column) {
  values <- pull(data, {{ column }})
  function(n) {
    sample(values, n)
  }
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

createGenerator(df, x)(2)
#> [1] 4 5
```

or you create `values` *within* the enclosed function. Then the pipe works.

```r
createGenerator <- function(data, column) {
  function(n) {
   values <- data %>% pull({{column}})
   values %>% sample(n)
  }
}

createGenerator(df, x)(2)
#> [1] 7 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me some insights and I have found that I've made super stupid mistake in my code. I had to surround creation with brackets like `(df %>% createGenerator(x))(1)` and then call result with some argument. So obvious :)